# Efficiently taking time slices of variable length in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to efficiently slice a DataFrame with a DatetimeIndex (similar to a resample or groupby operation), but the desired time slices are different lengths.

This is relatively easy to do by looping (see code below), but with large timeseries the multiple slices quickly becomes slow. Any suggestions on vectorising this/improving speed?

```
import pandas as pd, datetime as dt, numpy as np

#Example DataFrame with a DatetimeIndex
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=dt.datetime(2017,1,1), end=dt.datetime(2017,1,31), freq='h')
df = pd.Series(index = idx, data = np.random.rand(len(idx)))

#The slicer dataframe contains a series of start and end windows
slicer_df = pd.DataFrame(index = [1,2])
slicer_df['start_window'] = [dt.datetime(2017,1,2,2), dt.datetime(2017,1,6,12)]
slicer_df['end_window'] = [dt.datetime(2017,1,6,12), dt.datetime(2017,1,15,2)]

#The results should be stored to a dataframe, indexed by the index of the slicer dataframe
#This is the loop that I would like to vectorise
slice_results = pd.DataFrame()
slice_results['total'] = None
for index, row in slicer_df.iterrows():
    slice_results.loc[index,'total'] = df[(df.index >= row.start_window) &
                                          (df.index <= row.end_window)].sum()
```

NB. I've just realised that my particular data set has adjacent windows (ie. the start of one window corresponds to the end of the one before it), but the windows are of different lengths. It feels like there should be a way to perform a groupby or similar with only one pass over df...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorize this with searchsorted (assuming the datetime index is sorted, otherwise first sort):

```
In [11]: inds = np.searchsorted(df.index.values, slicer_df.values)

In [12]: s = df.cumsum()  # only sum once!

In [13]: pd.Series([s[end] - s[start-1] if start else s[end] for start, end in inds], slicer_df.index)
Out[13]:
1     36.381155
2    111.521803
dtype: float64
```

*There's still a loop in there, but it's now a lot cheaper!*

---

That leads us to a completely vectorized solution (it's a little more cryptic):

```
In [21]: inds2 = np.maximum(1, inds)  # see note

In [22]: inds2[:, 0] -= 1

In [23]: inds2
Out[23]:
array([[ 23,  96],
       [119, 336]])

In [24]: x = s[inds2]

In [25]: x
Out[25]:
array([[  11.4596498 ,   47.84080472],
       [  55.94941276,  167.47121538]])

In [26]: x[:, 1] - x[:, 0]
Out[26]: array([  36.38115493,  111.52180263])
```

*Note: the when the start date is before the first date we want to avoid the start index rolling back from 0 to -1 (which would mean the end of the array i.e. underflow).*

Comment: added this as separate answer... as it's a completely different approach!

Comment: that searchsorted is exactly what I was looking for. Vectorised solution at the end is very clever too. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this as an apply, which will concat the results rather than iteratively update the DataFrame:

```
In [11]: slicer_df.apply((lambda row: \
              df[(df.index >= row.start_window) 
               & (df.index <= row.end_window)].sum()), axis=1)
Out[11]:
1     36.381155
2    111.521803
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the looping or the DataFrame creation will be the bottleneck, but this at least alleviates the latter.

Comment: Hi Andy, that's a really neat trick to avoid the iterrows loop (+1), but unfortunately the lambda function still needs to perform the slice for each iteration. Once df is very large, each slice takes a long time, hence I'm running into a speed issue. Looking for a way to vectorise so that the slicing can all be performed concurrently.

Comment: @DaveB yeah, this one only saves on the DataFrame construction (avoiding the multiple slicing/building up). In general, I think the solution could involve sorting the datetime index (or can we already assume it's sorted?), reaching in to [searchsorted](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) for each start/end then using that to slice/sum.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a vectorised method which relies on the varying length "windows" being always adjacent to one another, ie. that the start of a window is the same as the end of the window before it.

```
# Ensure that the join will be successful by rounding to a specific frequency
round_freq = '1h'
df.index = df.index.round(round_freq)
slicer_df.start_window= slicer_df.start_window.dt.round(round_freq)

# Give the index of the slicer a useful name
slicer_df.index.name = 'event_number'

#Perform a join to the start of the window, forward fill to the next window, then groupby to get the totals for each time window
df = df.to_frame('orig_data').join(slicer_df.reset_index().set_index('start_window')[['event_number']])
df.event_number = df.event_number.ffill()
df.groupby('event_number').sum()
```

Of course this only works when the windows are adjacent, ie. they can't overlap or have any gaps. If anyone has a more general method that works for the above, I'd love to see it!